# The non-nullable local variable 'mockLoginRespository' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart, tdd, clean-architecture, dart-test

I am trying to develop my app using Clean TDD (Test Driven Development) Architecture. For the login feature , I am writing the test case as follows:

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:test_app/features/login/domain/entities/user.dart';
import 'package:test_app/features/login/domain/repositories/login_repository.dart';
import 'package:test_app/features/login/domain/usecases/call_login.dart';

class MockLoginRespository extends Mock implements LoginRepository {}

void main() {
  CallLogin usecase;
  MockLoginRespository mockLoginRespository;
  final tUserName = "test.user";
  final tPassword = "test.password";
  final tUser = User(
      userID: "test.userID", email: "test.email", userName: "test.userName");
  setUp(() {
    mockLoginRespository = MockLoginRespository();
    usecase = CallLogin(mockLoginRespository);
  });

  test(
    'should perform login from the repository',
    () async {
      when(mockLoginRespository.login(any, any))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tUser));

      final result =
          await usecase.execute(username: tUserName, password: tPassword);

      expect(result, Right(tUser));
      verify(mockLoginRespository.login(tUserName, tPassword));
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockLoginRespository);
    },
  );
}
```

I am getting error as :

`The non-nullable local variable 'mockLoginRespository' must be assigned before it can be used. Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.`

How should I properly initialize the mockLoginRepository?

I tried adding the initialization expression inside the test async function.

```
  test(
    'should perform login from the repository',
    () async {

  // Added initialization down here

    mockLoginRespository = MockLoginRespository();
    usecase = CallLogin(mockLoginRespository);
      when(mockLoginRespository.login(any, any))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tUser));
    .
    .
    .
    },`
```

This removes the error, but is it the right way to do it ? The code tutorial I follow doesn't make the initialization this way.

Comment: Cant see `GenerateMocks` before main method

Comment: The compiler cannot know the semantics of how `package:test` works; it does not know that `setUp` will be called before executing tests.  For this, just declare `mockLoginRespository` to be `late`.  Situations like this where you know better than the compiler are what that keyword is for.

Comment: Declaring `mockLoginRepository` as `late` works fine. I was confused because in the code tutorial I followed did not do this.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Isn't the `GenerateMocks` the automated method to generate mock class. I think the statement`class MockLoginRespository extends Mock implements LoginRepository {}` works manually instead of that.

Comment: @AllenPBiju No, with null-safety, you must use `@GenerateMocks` (or `@GenerateNiceMocks`).  [Manually creating a `Mock` class involves *much* more work](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md).